# Определение версии IE не работает (microsoft способ)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Испытываю код с сайта компании microsoft, но он мой IE определяет как седьмую версию хотя у меня восьмая (написано в About пункте). Что не так?

```js
function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
    var rv = -1;

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp('MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})');

        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }

    return rv;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код только для IE.

Шестую версию IE детектит нормально.

В чем причина?

содержимое переменной ua:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проверь в каком режиме открыта странице. Вполне возможно она открыта в режиме совместимости с IE7

Comment: @Grundy не помогло , действовал вот по этой инструкции https://help.inbox.lv/question/525/31?language=ru

Comment: @perfect UserAgent в студию. А так же советую посмотреть `document.documentMode`

Comment: @Sublihim добавил в вопрос , document.documentMode = 5

Comment: @perfect, ну вот же: `compatible; MSIE 7.0` Открой консоль и посмотри что действительно у тебя установлен режим совместимости. И добавь в вопрос полный код HTML который ты проверяешь. Вернее можно только `DOCTYPE`

Comment: @Grundy и из кода режим совместимости не переключается , пробовал вот это http://xiper.net/manuals/html/meta-tags/http-equiv/x-UA-Compatible

Comment: @perfect. Ну дык, да в режиме совместимости ) И посмотри на версию Trident - он у тебя 4, это сотвествует версии IE8 ) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Trident Определяй по трайденту, надежней ) А если html твой - мета должна быть такая `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >`

Comment: @perfect, дополнение: режим совместимости может быть навязан групповой политикой домена

Comment: @perfect `documentMode === 5` соответствует `quirks mode`

Comment: @Sublihim если файл имеет название file.html то проблем нет (как восмерку определяет) а он у меня file.hta , а мета '<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" >' там прописан. почему то через mshta результат другой. делаю как здесь написано https://recalll.co/app/?q=Javascript%20version%20in%20HTA

Comment: mshta-то тебе зачем?

Comment: @Sublihim нужен он мне )

Comment: @perfect. Вобщем, если тебе стандартными средствами не удается заставить браузер понять, что это IE8, советую проверить documentMode и если он 5, то смотри на версию Trident - он тебе точно скажет, какая версия IE.

Comment: @Sublihim спасибо так и поступлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогам комментариев, оформлю ответ. 
В данном случае, мне кажется алгоритм должен быть такой:

1. Определить `document.documentMode`,
2. Если `documentMode ===5`, (следовательно *IE* находится в `quirks mode`).
   выполнить **п.3** иначе **п.4**
3. Определить версию [Trident](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Trident) и по ней вычислить версию *IE*
4. Определить версию *IE* предложенным в ответе способом